# How can I make the legend's similar to the stacked bar chart (and change the legend's label) in D3 v6?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I am creating a stacked bar chart with D3 right now and trying to add a legend to explain about the data. However, my legend's color is different with the one in the stacked bar chart.[image: The example for my chart]

Here is the code for my chart: (I put here only the relevant part for the legend's color, since the whole file is too long):

```
let dataset = [{Year:'2006-2007',Energy_Recovery: 44, Disposal : 190, Recycling: 2},
               {Year:'2008-2009',Energy_Recovery: 40, Disposal : 189, Recycling: 1},
               {Year:'2009-2010',Energy_Recovery: 38, Disposal : 180, Recycling: 2},
               {Year:'2010-2011',Energy_Recovery: 41, Disposal : 167, Recycling: 2},
               {Year:'2013-2014',Energy_Recovery: 44, Disposal : 150, Recycling: 7},    
               {Year:'2014-2015',Energy_Recovery: 43, Disposal : 127, Recycling: 21},
               {Year:'2015-2016',Energy_Recovery: 49, Disposal : 117, Recycling: 20},
               {Year:'2016-2017',Energy_Recovery: 47, Disposal : 120, Recycling: 24},
               {Year:'2017-2018',Energy_Recovery: 46, Disposal : 111, Recycling: 24},
               {Year:'2018-2019',Energy_Recovery: 41, Disposal : 109, Recycling: 24}];

let first_stack = ["Energy_Recovery", "Disposal", "Recycling"];
let stack = d3.stack().keys(first_stack).order(d3.stackOrderDescending); 
let series = stack(dataset);

 //Create SVG element
let svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

let colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var size = 10;
svg.selectAll("mydots")
  .data(first_stack)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 750)
    .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 20 + i*(size+5);}) 
    .attr("width", size)
    .attr("height", size)
    .style("fill", function(d){ return colors(d);});

// Add one dot in the legend for each name.
svg.selectAll("mylabels")
  .data(first_stack)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("x", 750 + size*1.2)
    .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 25 + i*(size+5) + (size/2);}) 
    .style("fill", function(d){ return colors(d);})
    .text(function(d){ return d;})
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .style("alignment-baseline", "middle");
```

Does anyone know how to handle this problem? And also, can anyone help me to change the label in the legend from 'Energy_Recovery' to 'Energy Recovery'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need this:

```
let colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

You can define `colors` as an array:

```
const colors = ['orange', 'blue', 'green'];
```

... and then assign those colors to the legend's points and labels by index:

```
svg.selectAll("mydots")
  .data(first_stack)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  ...
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colors[i]);

// Add one dot in the legend for each name.
svg.selectAll("mylabels")
  .data(first_stack)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  ...
  .text(d => d)
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colors[i]);
```